# Elegir ruta donde subir archivo a servidor PHP

Tags: php

Buenos dias,
Quiero subir un archivo a un servidor mediante PHP. Ya lo logré, el tema es que quiero generar un boton para poder elegir el directorio donde va a situarse ese archivo.

Pueden ayudarme?

El codigo que tengo actualmente es:

```
<?php
$archivo = (isset($_FILES['archivo'])) ? $_FILES['archivo'] : null;
if ($archivo) {
   $extension = pathinfo($archivo['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $extension = strtolower($extension);
   $extension_correcta = ($extension == 'jpg' or $extension == 'jpeg' or $extension == 'gif' or $extension == 'png' or $extension == 'svg');
   if ($extension_correcta) {
      $ruta_destino_archivo = "img/{$archivo['name']}";
      $archivo_ok = move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], $ruta_destino_archivo);
   }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title> Subir archivos </title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <?php if (isset($archivo)): ?>
       <?php if (!$extension_correcta): ?>
         <span style="color: #f00;"> La extensión es incorrecta, el archivo debe ser jpg, jpeg, gif o png. </span>
       <?php elseif (!$archivo_ok): ?>
         <span style="color: #f00;"> Error al intentar subir el archivo. </span>
      <?php else: ?>
         <strong> El archivo ha sido subido correctamente. </strong>
         <br />
         <img src="archivos/<?php echo $archivo['name'] ?>" alt="" />
      <?php endif ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <form method="post" action="subir-archivo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label> Archivo </label>
      <input type="file" name="archivo" required="required" />
      <input type="submit" value="Subir" />
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Quiero poder elegir el directorio $ruta_destino_archivo.

Alguien me puede ayudar?
Gracias

Comment: ¿Quieres que te aparezca un listado de rutas disponibles a partir de un directorio dado o quieres que el usuario escriba libremente la ruta en un campo de texto?

Answer (score 1):

Una opcion sería en un select cargar los directorios con `scandir` y ya con esa selección puedes armar la ruta en tu php. y para tratar mejor las rutas puedes checar esto.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.realpath.php

http://php.net/manual/es/function.scandir.php

Comment: Es muy puntual el tema del directorio? Puede ser en cualquier directorio del SO? O en algunos específicos? Lo pregunto por el tema de la seguridad

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un input en donde coloques el nombre del archivo o simplemente usando checkbox, de tal manera te aseguras de que no escriban un nombre de archivo mal intencionado.

```
<?php
$archivo = (isset($_FILES['archivo'])) ? $_FILES['archivo'] : null;
$ruta_destino_archivo = null;
if ($archivo) {
   $extension = pathinfo($archivo['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $extension = strtolower($extension);
   $extension_correcta = ($extension == 'jpg' or $extension == 'jpeg' or $extension == 'gif' or $extension == 'png' or $extension == 'svg');
   if ($extension_correcta) {
      if(isset($_POST["directorio"])){
         if($_POST["directorio"] == 0){
            $ruta_destino_archivo = "img/{$archivo['name']}";
         }else if($_POST["directorio"] == 1){
            $ruta_destino_archivo = "css/{$archivo['name']}";
         }else if($_POST["directorio"] == 2){
            $ruta_destino_archivo = "js/{$archivo['name']}";
         }
      }else{
          $ruta_destino_archivo = "img/{$archivo['name']}";
      }
      $archivo_ok = move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], $ruta_destino_archivo);
   }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title> Subir archivos </title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <?php if (isset($archivo)): ?>
       <?php if (!$extension_correcta): ?>
         <span style="color: #f00;"> La extensión es incorrecta, el archivo debe ser jpg, jpeg, gif o png. </span>
       <?php elseif (!$archivo_ok): ?>
         <span style="color: #f00;"> Error al intentar subir el archivo. </span>
      <?php else: ?>
         <strong> El archivo ha sido subido correctamente. </strong>
         <br />
         <img src="archivos/<?php echo $archivo['name'] ?>" alt="" />
      <?php endif ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <form method="post" action="subir-archivo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label> Archivo </label>
      <input type="file" name="archivo" required="required" />
      <label> img/nombre_archivo </label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="directorio" value="0" required="required" />
      <label> css/nombre_archivo </label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="directorio" value="1" required="required" />
      <label> js/nombre_archivo </label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="directorio" value="2" required="required" />

      <input type="submit" value="Subir" />
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma, o colocando un input text que te permita obtener el directorio que deseas, pero tienes que tener cuidado con temas de seguridad, por que si te colocan un directorio ajeno del tipo /etc/ /var/ o /home/ puede generarte una brecha de seguridad.